# Create a variable named from a string OR create a string from a variables name

Tags: php, string, variables

So this all stemmed from not wanting to check each POST in a huge If statement with tons of ANDs like so:

```
if(isset($_POST[$question], $_POST[$choice1], $_POST[$choice2], $_POST[$choice3], $_POST[$choice4], $_POST[$choice5], $_POST[$password]) && 
    strlen(question > 0) &&
    strlen(choice1 > 0) &&
    strlen(choice2 > 0) &&
    strlen(choice3 > 0) &&
    strlen(choice4 > 0) &&
    strlen(choice5 > 0) &&
    strlen(password > 0)) 
{
    $cat=$_POST['cat'];
    $question=$_POST['question'];
    $choice1=$_POST['choice1'];
    $choice2=$_POST['choice2'];
    $choice3=$_POST['choice3'];
    $choice4=$_POST['choice4'];
    $choice5=$_POST['choice5'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
}
else{
    //Incorrect password or missing data
}
```

Instead I created an array with a string for each variable I wanted to check for and a foreach loop to run my tests

```
//create array with all wanted variables
$variables = array('cat', 'question', 'choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3', 'choice4', 'choice5', 'password');
$returnError = FALSE;
//run through array to check that all have been posted and meet requirements
foreach($variables as $var) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$var]) || !strlen($_POST[$var]) > 0) {
        $returnError = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now I want to take the string names and instantiate variables with the same name

```
//create array with all wanted variables
$variables = array('cat', 'question', 'choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3', 'choice4', 'choice5', 'password');
$returnError = FALSE;
//run through array to check that all have been posted and meet requirements
foreach($variables as $var) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$var]) || !strlen($_POST[$var]) > 0) {
        $returnError = TRUE;
        break;
    }
    else{
        global $*/variable named $var*/ = $_POST[$var];
    }
}
```

Is that possible?  If not, how would I do something similar with an array of variables like so:

```
$variables = array($cat,$question,$choice1,$choice2,$choice3,$choice4,$choice5,$password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), although it is not recommended.

```
global $$var = $_POST[$var];
```

Comment: This causes a parse error.  Doing this fixes it:

`global $$var;
$$var = $_POST[$var];`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Use eval();
http://www.php.net/eval

Be aware that creating variable with eval() from post data could be a security risk.